# Ruby version control

Tags: macos, version-control

Developing on a Mac and will host on Linux.  Does any know of a good/reliable version control plugin or hosting platform I can us during development?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: What IDE or text editor are you using? XCode? VIM? Emacs? Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen (I'm still trying to get into Ruby and Rails, so this is a bit of an outsider's perspective) it seems that git is intimately tied up with quite a lot of Rails stuff. For that matter, most of the Rails open-source community seems to be based around github.com.

Given that, I would personally go with git. If you want/need an IDE that integrates with it, JetBrains' RubyMine should support it ( http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html ) and I believe there is also a git bundle for TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

[`git`](http://git-scm.com/) is the usual choice here for version control. You won't really need a separate plugin to get it to work; git is just a set of command-line tools.

Answer (score 1):

Git or SVN

You can use GitHub http://github.com/ or Unfuddle http://unfuddle.com/ to host.

Answer (score 0):

Git or SVN are the obvious choices. I would recommend whatever one the majority of the libaries you use for projects utilize as its easier to manage external libs in your own projects. Additionally, it also depends on how you want to use it. Forexampel if you want integration in an IDE, or a pretty GUI, or if youre cool with the command line.

For me all this boils down to Subversion (SVN) though i suspect since youre using Ruby and presumably Rails youll probably want to go with Git.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `Subversion` all the way.

Especially since the tooling support (in my opinion) is better for Subversion. Since you are on the Mac check out [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) to manage you Svn working copy. On your Linux box you can just simply use the command line tools.

As for hosting, I've personally used http://unfuddle.com/, and was pleased with them. The only downside is the price you have to pay to get SSL support for you code. But if SSL isn't a concern, then they even have a free tier of service.